# Use an model-equation in model ARIMA to predict for many different series?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I want to test adaptable of a model. Examples, i have series of quantity products from 1990 to 2010 `products2010`:

```
products2010<-c(198,150,120,84,150,136,80,128,160,132,144,234,300,312,400,468,420,500,650,612,516)
```

I found the best model for this series: `fit1` - `ARIMA (3,1,0)` with `ar1=0.4373, ar2=-0.5163,ar3=0.7163` and predict for 2011. I get forecast value in 2011 for seires `products2010`: `601`.
Now i want to test adaptable of a model, i add real value in 2011 in to series `products2010`, to form a new series `products2011` (this's the real series from 1990 to 2011):

```
products2011<-c(198,150,120,84,150,136,80,128,160,132,144,234,300,312,400,468,420,500,650,612,516,580)
```

and i want to use model - equation series `products2010` to forecast for series `products2011` (This's - i want to use `fit1` to forecast fore series `products2011`) and get forecast value in 2012. But i can't find method to do this. I thought to function `predict()` in R with argument `newxreg`, but i don't know to use it.
How can i do this?

Comment: How did you determine the best model for your series? Also what type of data do you have, yearly product sales? `newxreg` should be a matrix that contains future values for an exogenous predictor variable.

Comment: Thanks @Rick Arko. I know how determine the best model for your series. Here i only want to find a way to apply one fixed model for many different series. This's mean, i want to test adaptable of model